# Add multiples Items from ListBox1 to a Binding multiple items ListBox2

Tags: wpf, listbox

I am getting some experience in WPF by now. But, there is a problem i can´t figure out. Add or remove items To/from a binding Listbox! All examples that i´ve seen shows only colletions of one single item. If anyone provide an example of a collection with more than one single item i´ll be very thankful.

```
    interface DbInterface 
{

    ObservableCollection<fichaProduto> carregaFichaProduto(int? fichaId);

}
     public class fichaProduto
{
    public int fichaProdutoFichaId { get; set; }
    public int fichaProdutoProdutoId {get;set;}
    public string fichaProdutoProdutoNome { get; set; }
    public string fichaProdutoStatusId { get; set; }
    public string fichaProdutoStatusNome { get; set; }
    public string fichaProdutoOrdemServico { get; set; }
    public DateTime? fichaProdutoDataInstalacao { get; set; }
    public string fichaProdutoHorarioDe { get; set; }
    public string fichaProdutoHorarioAte { get; set; }
    public string fichaProdutoContrato { get; set; }
    public string fichaProdutoCodigoInstalacao { get; set; }
    public Decimal fichaProdutoValor { get; set; }
}
   class dbMysql : DbInterface
   {
    public ObservableCollection<fichaProduto> carregaFichaProduto(int? fichaId)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection smartConexaoDb = new MySqlConnection(smartSingleTon.connectionStringDb))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT fc.id,pp.nome,st.nome,fp.os,fp.dia_instalacao,fp.horarioDe,fp.horarioAte,fp.contrato,fp.codigo_instalacao,fp.valor FROM ficha fc JOIN ficha_produto fp ON fc.id = fp.id_ficha LEFT JOIN ficha_produto fp2 ON (fc.id = fp2.id_ficha AND fp.id < fp2.id) JOIN produto_plano pp ON pp.id = fp.id_produto JOIN status st ON fp.id_status = st.id WHERE fc.id = @fichaId ORDER BY fc.id DESC", smartConexaoDb))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fichaId", fichaId);
                smartConexaoDb.Open();

                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var listFichaProduto = new ObservableCollection<fichaProduto>();

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        listFichaProduto.Add
                            (new fichaProduto()
                            {
                                fichaProdutoFichaId = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(0)),
                                fichaProdutoProdutoNome = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(1)),
                                fichaProdutoStatusNome = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(2)),
                                fichaProdutoOrdemServico = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(3)),
                                fichaProdutoHorarioDe = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(5)),
                                fichaProdutoHorarioAte = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(6)),
                                fichaProdutoContrato = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(7)),
                                fichaProdutoCodigoInstalacao = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(8)),
                                fichaProdutoValor = Convert.ToDecimal(dr.GetValue(9))
                            });
                    }
                    return listFichaProduto;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

obs: Listbox 2 is binding from this method below:

```
 public ObservableCollection<fichaProduto> carregaFichaProduto(int? fichaId)
```

it shows two items from the fichaProduto Class on it. fichaProdutoProdutoNome  and fichaProdutoValor.

ListBox 1 binding data from another and more complete ObservableCollection product DB query.

So , from ListBox1 all i want it´s to ADD items to ListBox2 or even REMOVE then FROM ListBox2.

I know how to do it in WnForms but not in WPF by now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i will do is to load a new SQl Query to update my ObservableCollection List and get it back again to ItemsSource.